# Unable to connect to the MTS Mblaze usb

Tags: usb

```
PCEH25EN:~$ sudo apt-get install wvdial
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

When I happen to install the above code, I've been displayed with the message stated above. Would you please get me the answers to resolve the issue and to connect to INTERNET using the device.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Even the USB is not showing up.

Here is some more info, I would like to provide

```
$ sudo wvdialconf
Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

Scanning your serial ports for a modem.

Modem Port Scan<*1>: S0   S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6   S7   
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S8   S9   S10  S11  S12  S13  S14  S15  
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S16  S17  S18  S19  S20  S21  S22  S23  
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S24  S25  S26  S27  S28  S29  S30  S31  


Sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program?
Did you configure it properly with setserial?

Please read the FAQ at http://alumnit.ca/wiki/?WvDial
surya@prominere-VPCEH25EN:~$ sudo wvdialconf
Editing `/etc/wvdial.conf'.

Scanning your serial ports for a modem.

Modem Port Scan<*1>: S0   S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6   S7   
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S8   S9   S10  S11  S12  S13  S14  S15  
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S16  S17  S18  S19  S20  S21  S22  S23  
Modem Port Scan<*1>: S24  S25  S26  S27  S28  S29  S30  S31  
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 Z -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0 -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Modem Identifier: ATI -- Manufacturer: QUALCOMM INCORPORATED
ttyUSB0<*1>: Speed 9600: AT -- OK
ttyUSB0<*1>: Max speed is 9600; that should be safe.
ttyUSB0<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0 -- OK
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 2400 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 9600 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB1<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- and failed too at 115200, giving up.
ttyUSB2<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 2400 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB2<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 9600 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB2<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- and failed too at 115200, giving up.
ttyUSB3<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 2400 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB3<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 9600 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB3<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- and failed too at 115200, giving up.
ttyUSB4<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 2400 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB4<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- failed with 9600 baud, next try: 9600 baud
ttyUSB4<*1>: ATQ0 V1 E1 -- and failed too at 115200, giving up.

Found a modem on /dev/ttyUSB0.
Modem configuration written to /etc/wvdial.conf.
ttyUSB0<Info>: Speed 9600; init "ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0"
surya@prominere-VPCEH25EN:~$ gksudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
surya@prominere-VPCEH25EN:~$ sudo wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Configuration does not specify a valid phone number.
--> Configuration does not specify a valid login name.
--> Configuration does not specify a valid password.
```

Comment: I am getting same error on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS while trying to connect Tata Photon+(Huawei E152)

Comment: I fixed it. number, username and password line were commented with ```;``` in wvdial.conf